# C# algorithm searching words by numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have to write algotithm in C# where input is:

```
3 2
aj
oj
ck
25
73
```

and the output:

```
aj ck
DOES NOT EXIST
```

The first line in iput is two numbers, the first one is number of words. And the second one is number of numbers for which we will be searching for words. Each character is represented by number like this below:

```
 2 (abc)
 3 (def)
 4 (ghi)
 5 (jkl)
 6 (mno)
 7 (pqrs)
 8 (tuv)
 9 (wxyz)
```

For example for number 25, there are 9 two-char-words: aj, ak, al, bj, bk, bl, cj, ck, cl.
For number 438, there are 27 three-char-words, etc.

So far I have this code, but something is not working properly, and I have no idea what is it that is not working.

```
int n;
int k;
string input;
List<string> dict = new List<string>();
List<string> res = new List<string>();
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    dict.Add(input);
}
dict.Sort();
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    res = new List<string>(dict);
    int inputLength = input.Length;
    for (int j = 0; j < inputLength; ++j)
    {
        switch (input[j])
        {
            case '2':
                res = new List<string>(filter(res, i, 'a', 'b', 'c'));
                break;
            case '3':
                res = new List<string>(filter(res, i, 'd', 'e', 'f'));
                break;
            case '4':
                break;
            case '5':
                res = new List<string>(filter(res, i, 'j', 'k', 'l'));
                break;
            case '6':
                res = new List<string>(filter(res, i, 'm', 'n', 'o'));
                break;
            case '7':
                res = new List<string>(filterWithFour(res, i, 'p', 'q', 'r', 's'));
                break;
            case '8':
                res = new List<string>(filter(res, i, 't', 'u', 'v'));
                break;
            case '9':
                res = new List<string>(filterWithFour(res, i, 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'));
                break;
        }
    }
    if (res.Any())
        foreach (var item in res.ToList())
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("DOES NOT EXIST");
}

static List<string> filterWithFour(List<string> resGiven, int pos, char a, char b, char c, char d)
{
    List<string> res = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in resGiven.ToList())
    {
        if (item.Length > pos)
            if (item[pos] == a || item[pos] == b || item[pos] == c || item[pos] == d)
                res.Add(item);
    }
    return res;
}

static List<string> filter(List<string> resGiven, int pos, char a, char b, char c)
{
    List<string> res = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in resGiven.ToList())
    {
        if (item.Length > pos)
            if (item[pos] == a || item[pos] == b || item[pos] == c)
                res.Add(item);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Thank you for any help, because I stuck on this one, and I can't go through it.

Comment: What does 'not working properly' mean exactly?

Comment: @nicomp i always get answer DOES NOT EXIST, while it should give me something.

Comment: Have you already stepped through your program with [the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)? If so, where in your program does it do something different from what you expected?

Comment: Can you explain why you expect `aj ck` and then `DOES NOT EXIST` as the output? What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: @Sweeper 25 means find any string that matches `[abc][jkl]` so you get `aj ck`, and 73 means `[pqrs][def]` and no string matches that, so you get `DOES NOT EXIST`

Comment: @Jolof are you allowed to use `Regex`? If so, I suggest you use it, as it would be waaaay easier

Comment: @Rafalon yes i can use regex, and i will try this later, cause now i do not have acces to computer, and i will try to give if this worked

Comment: @Jolof Can you share a C# online demo link? Also, a `trie` data structure of already given list of words(`aj`,`ck` etc) seems to a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do what you want, I would replace the numbers with Regex pattern as such:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; // so you can use .Where on List
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int n;
        int k;
        string input;
        List<string> dict = new List<string>();
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            dict.Add(input);
        }
        dict.Sort();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            // get the full pattern for the whole number
            string patternToSearch = "";
            foreach(var c in input)
            {
                patternToSearch += GetPattern(c);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(patternToSearch);

            // find the words that matches the pattern
            var filteredDict = dict.Where(w => Regex.Match(w, patternToSearch).Success);

            if(!filteredDict.Any())
                Console.WriteLine("DOES NOT EXIST");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", filteredDict));
        }
    }

    // returns the regex pattern for one number
    static string GetPattern(char c)
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case '2': return "[abc]";
            case '3': return "[def]";
            case '4': return "[ghi]";
            case '5': return "[jkl]";
            case '6': return "[mno]";
            case '7': return "[pqrs]";
            case '8': return "[tuv]";
            case '9': return "[wxyz]";
            default: return "";
        }
    }
}
```

With input:

```
3
2
aj
oj
ck
25
73
```

It outputs:

```
[abc][jkl]
aj ck
[pqrs][def]
DOES NOT EXIST
```

Comment: Not a C# dev, but just curious to know why dict.Sort() is necessary. Because if you are sorting, you could at least take the privilege of doing a binary search.

Comment: @vivek_23 it is not necessary, I just didn't remove it from OP's code (I guess it's here so we return the results in the right order). Note that we are (or at least I am) **not** talking about performance here (and I am assuming low amounts of data) but more about readability